# Getting subgraph of nodes between two nodes?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have this graph:

```
%matplotlib inline 
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edge(1, 2)
G.add_edge(2, 3)
G.add_edge(3, 4)
G.add_edge(3, 5)
G.add_edge(4, 6)
G.add_edge(5, 6)
G.add_edge(3, 7)
G.add_edge(7, 6)
G.add_edge(6, 8)
G.add_edge(8, 9)

nx.draw(G, pos=nx.spring_layout(G), with_labels=True)
```

[image]

Is it possible to get the subgraph between the nodes 3 and 6 without using `nx.subgraph(G, [3,4,5,6,7])`. I mean, what if I know that there is this subgraph, but I don't know e.g. about the 5?

Comment: If I add 3 edges to your graph with `G.add_edges_from([(3,10),(10,11),(11,6)])` (which creates a new path from 3 to 6 but it goes through nodes 10 and 11 so it's longer than the others) - do you want 10 and 11 to be in your subgraph?

Comment: I've edited your title to more closely match your question.  Please double check it.  Also, you can more compactly generate your graph with `G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6), (3, 7), (7, 6), (6, 8), (8, 9)])`, so you might edit your question to show that.

Comment: But this line is not PEP8 compliant. :-)

Comment: deleting my answer... it doesn't work. but have an idea for a new one that won't take hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is very similar to back2basics, but more directly finds the nodes between the two.  If there is a path from `source` to `target`, that path will be found by `nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=source, target=target)` which returns a generator for the paths.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6), (3, 7), (7, 6), (6, 8), (8, 9)])

paths_between_generator = nx.all_simple_paths(G,source=3,target=6)
nodes_between_set = {node for path in paths_between_generator for node in path}
SG = G.subgraph(nodes_between_set)
```

the `nodes_between_set = ...` uses a "set generator".  It is equivalent to

```
nodes_between_set = set()
for path in paths_beween_generator:
    for node in path:
        nodes_between_set.add(node)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first 3 lines help made the list that you need to make the subset.

```
import networkx as nx

c_score = nx.algorithms.betweenness_centrality_subset(G,(3,), (6,))
nodes_between = [x for x in c_score if c_score[x]!=0.0]
nodes_between.extend((3,6))  #add on the ends
SG = G.subgraph(nodes_between)

nx.draw(SG, pos=nx.spring_layout(SG), with_labels=True)
```

One caveat: The subgraph points are defined as being in a path from point 3 to point 6

Comment: I think `betweenness_centrality_subset` will only give nonzero entries if they are on the shortest path between two nodes.  If you add edges 3-10, 10-11, 11-6 to the given `G`, both 10 and 11 will not be in `SG`.

Comment: I have double checked this and `betweenness_centrality_subset` gives 0 for 10 and 11...

Comment: Wouldn't have noticed that on this dataset. TY.

Answer (score 0):

This works on the principle that

1. any node in the new subgraph is reachable from source or destination, and
2. any node on the path by definition has at least one predecessor and one successor (for a directed graph) or two neighbors (for an undirected graph).

So, first we find the subgraph of nodes that we can reach, and then recursively remove nodes without at least one predecessor and one successor until there is only the existing subgraph.

```
import networkx as nx
def subgraph_from_connections(G, source, target, directed = None):
    included_nodes = [x for x in G.node if nx.has_path(G, source, x) and nx.has_path(G, x, target)]
    G2 = G.subgraph(included_nodes)
    # If this is a undirected graph, we only need to know if it only has 1 neighbor
    # If this is a directed graph, then it needs at least 1 predecessor and at least 1 successor
    if directed == True or (directed is None and type(G) == nx.classes.digraph.DiGraph):
        removals = [x for x in G2.node if len(G2.predecessors(x)) == 0 or len(G2.successors(x)) == 0]
        while len(removals) > 0:
            G2.remove_nodes_from(removals)
            removals = [x for x in G.node if len(G2.predecessors(x)) == 0 or len(G2.successors(x)) == 0]
    else:
        removals = [x for x in G2.node if len(G2.neighbors(x)) < 2]
        while len(removals) > 0:
            G2.remove_nodes_from(removals)
            removals = [x for x in G2.node if len(G2.neighbors(x)) < 2]
    return G2
```

Not extensively tested, but it worked for the few cases outlined here, and it includes 10/11 when those were included from Joel's test. The algorithm is fast enough - 130 ms for my 1000/10 node random test from before (maybe I shouldn't have deleted that after all).